# What is this bag that came with a bike?

Tags: road-bike, accessories

I can't figure out the point of this bag that came with a Canyon road bike.  It has velcro straps on top and bottom and a velcro enclosure for the top.  The top also has loops on each side of the enclosure.  The front of the bag has an additional pocket.  I'm totally stumped as to what this bag is supposed to be for.  What is it?

It's 10.5 inches by 14.5 inches (27 cm by 37 cm)

[image]

Comment: I don't recognise the logo but its definitely not the canyon one, so its not provided with the bike.

Comment: @Criggie, that is assuredly the Canyon logo.

Comment: @hmqcnosey I was going to disagree, but you're right - https://ih1.redbubble.net/image.3435047125.1182/st,small,507x507-pad,600x600,f8f8f8.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it’s supposed to be used like the Topeak Burrito Pack? https://www.topeak.com/global/en/product/1283-BURRITO-PACK

[image: Topeak Burrito on top tube]

Or maybe it’s completely unrelated to bicycles. My Rose road bike came with a gym bag and a zip folder.